# Почему не работает try with resourses?

Tags: java

Практикуюсь в сериализации. Пишу такой код:

```
import java.io.*;

public class SerializeMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Chocolate chocolateOutput = new Chocolate("Jonny Depp", "Julite Miniut",
            200, "Djudi Dench");

    FileOutputStream fos;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("db.txt");
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

        oos.writeObject(chocolateOutput);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (oos != null) {
                oos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Chocolate chocolateInput = null;

    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("db.txt")))) {
        chocolateInput = (Chocolate) ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(chocolateInput);
    }
}
}
```

Но почему-то пишет, что `chocolateInput` is always null.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 5):

Это происходит потому, что когда вы попадаете в этот блок

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(chocolateInput);
}
```

Метод `ois.readObject()` еще не прочитал объект из файла - исключение произойдет раньше, или в нем самом. Поэтому `System.out.println(chocolateInput)` не имеет смысла. Внутри `catch` обьект `chocolateInput` всегда будет указывать на null.

Вы также можете переписать свой код, чтобы сделать его покороче и более читаемым:

```
String filename = "db.txt";

try ( ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))) ) {
    oos.writeObject(new Chocolate("Jonny Depp", "Julite Miniut", 200, "Djudi Dench"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try ( ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) ) {
    Chocolate chocolateInput = (Chocolate) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(chocolateInput);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```